# How to merge two columns into one in csv format (Python Pandas)?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I crawled a table from html and parsed it into a csv file. Yet the format of the table on the web changed in the middle, yet they didn't update the previous rows, so some of the columns are deprecated. Looks something like this:
[image]

the two columns in the red box are deprecated and they should be dropped, and the two columns to the right should replace them. How would I do this in Pandas?

After crawling, the csv file looks like this:
[image]

In a nutshell, I want to drop some columns from a certain row, and replace them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've met a similar problem, and solved it outside of pandas, and then merged the dataframes corresponding to the two kind of rows:

```
A = []
B = []

with open(your_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line.split(your_separator)) == expected_number_of_columns:
            A.append(line.split(your_separator))

        else:
            B.append(line.split(your_separator))
```

Here you have stored in the two lists of lists A and B the lines corresponding to the two kind of format in your csv file.

```
A = pd.DataFrame(A,columns = list_of_columns)
B = pd.DataFrame(B,columns = list_of_columns_2).drop(columns_to_drop,1)
df = pd.concat([A,B]).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: Expected number of columns should be the number of columns after truncation? EDIT: nvm It should be the original one.

Comment: Yes, `A` stores the part of your csv which is correctly formated (note that this code only works if you have two kind of formats, otherwise you have to add other `if` conditions).